# Compile Linux OpenGL Application on Windows?

Tags: c++, opengl, g++, mingw, cross-compiling

I have made  a OpenGL application which I can compile fine on Linux. It uses static .a librarys. Now I tried compiling with MinGW (and .lib libraries) and g++, but the resulting main.exe displays this error when I try to execute it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCOmi.png.

```
g++.exe -std=c++11 -Wall -o main.exe Main.cpp FastNoise.cpp shader.cpp texture.cpp glew32.lib glfw3.dll -lglu32 -lopengl32
```

When using cmake with the CMakeGUI to create a Visual Studio Project it works fine:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
add_definitions(-DGLEW_STATIC)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
add_executable(main Main.cpp texture.cpp shader.cpp FastNoise.cpp)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
IF (WIN32)
  target_link_libraries(main ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/GLEW_1130.lib ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/glfw3.lib ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARY} ${X11_LIBRARIES})
 configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vertex.glsl ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Debug/vertex.glsl COPYONLY)
 configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/fragment.glsl ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Debug/fragment.glsl COPYONLY)
 configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dirt.bmp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Debug/dirt.bmp COPYONLY)
ELSE()
  include_directories( ${X11_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
  find_package(X11 REQUIRED)
  target_link_libraries(main ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libGLEW.a ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libglfw3.a ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARY} ${X11_LIBRARIES} X11 Xxf86vm pthread dl Xrandr Xinerama Xcursor)
ENDIF()
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're asking to do on the command line. I assume that git would help you a great deal. You can also have #ifdef's in the files to check if you're on windows or linux

Comment: You're going to have to recompile the libraries and then the whole project. It's likely going to be easier to just create a new VS project to do all of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you have static libraries that doesn't mean that these are in any way system independent. The static libraries you have are all built for a Linux target. They expect to talk with Linux operating system functions using the a calling convention (i.e. the way functions are to be called) that's different from Windows. Essentially you're trying to shove a square peg through a round hole here. It doesn't work that way.

To build for Windows you need also all the prerequisites being ported and built for Windows, too. Luckily all the libraries you mention have Windows ports, so that's not a problem.

> I fixed it by adding these praeprocessor definitions:
>
> ```
> …
> ```

You fixed nothing. You just lied to *something* (compiler, your program source code, etc.) about the toolchain it's built with and the target it's built for.

If you start redefining system level preprocessor definitions, you're doing something very, very wrong.

Here's what you should do (well, what I recommend): Head over to http://www.msys2.org/ and grab the MSys2 installer. Install it, launch the MinGW… environment (there's a 32 bit and a 64 bit environment). MSys2 uses the *Pacman* package manager of the Arch Linux distribution. Use that to install the toolchain (make, binutils, gcc) – make sure you install the right variant, the package database has packages for msys, mingw32 and mingw64 – and all the development libraries you need. There are packages for GLEW, GLFW3 and so on available.

Next install *CMake*. I strongly recommend **not** to use the MSys2 package, but the standalone installer from https://cmake.org/ – the CMake installed this way knows how to work with MSys/MinGW …and more.

Then create a `CMakeLists.txt` for your project, *and use that to create the build environment.* The nice thing about CMake is, that it's cross platform and knows a ton of build systems and compiler environments. If your project is structured sanely and you don't do crazy stuff (or you do crazy stuff and put the right straightjackets around it so it doesn't go on a rampage) you'll get something that you can build effortlessly on or for most target environments.

Comment: I actually did something very similiar, as I did manage to fix it yesterday after trying for 7 long hours. I used CMakeLists to make just the same as my g++ compiler with either .lib or .a files depending on the system. Then I used CMakeGUI and made a Visual Studio Project from it and Visual Studio then compiled me a .exe. I don't know why I can't just simply do this with g++.exe tho. If you could take a look: https://hastebin.com/ocedatequc.lisp and this is my g++.exe version which should do the same but has undefined reference errors: https://hastebin.com/camaculufo.css

Comment: I just manged to get it to compile by using Win32 binaries and for glfw3 I actually used a .dll cuz they don't provide a .lib for MinGW. I now have a .exe but when I try to execute it I get this error https://i.imgur.com/dpidmsw.png and I compiled with this https://hastebin.com/ubipazapen.cpp. I have compiled with glew32s.lib and GLEW_STATIC define but I get the same result except my .exe is 800 kb bigger.

Comment: @QuesterDesura: Can you upload your whole project somewhere? Preferably a Git or Mercurial repository?

Comment: https://github.com/PowerOfCreation/C-Minecraftclone - It works with Cmake and Cmake GUI for VS but I can't get it to compile with g++.exe... I have tried pretty much all .libs and .dlls from GLFW and GLEW I did find... Would be amazing if I wouldn't need so switch over to Windows and use CMakeGUI to create a VS Project every time I want to compile for Windows...

Comment: I edited my initial Thread with the error I'm now facing. I hope it's now clear what my problem is.

Comment: @QuesterDesura: I cleaned up a little the build configuration and added a helper script. You can find the result at this repository: https://github.com/datenwolf-code-consulting/C-Minecraftclone **–** a few important pointers: Never put a custom `GL` include directory into your codebase. All the OpenGL includes are considered part of the system distribution and you must not mask them with custom headers. Note that it's perfectly okay to use headers as generated by glLoadGen, as these will use different names. With what I created just clone the repo, enter it's directory and call `./build.sh`

Comment: Alright. thank you - I tried it out and it worked except the GLEW_LIBRARY thing, it tells me it is not being found which is probably a issue as I'm only on the Ubuntu Bash for Windows currently. When linking with glew32.a from my other project it works. If I want to compile for windows I still need to create a VS Project and then make a .exe there, right?

Comment: @QuesterDesura: Actually I wrote the whole build.sh script for building in a MSys/MinGW environment on Windows. I tested it there and it should work right out of the box.

Comment: Sorry, but this is my first time using CMake and I don't know how to do such thing. I have researched and installed the MSys base now as well. I tried executing build.sh with `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\sh build.sh` and I get the error git not found. When I comment it out then I get the error mkdir not found and when I comment that out and create the folder myself then I get this error https://hastebin.com/irodorurul.vbs. I suppose I need to somehow install a compiler or something like that, but I have no clue - this is my first time compiling other than g++.

Comment: @QuesterDesura: Ohh, I forgot adding to autoinstall Git in that repo. Um, Just do a `pacman -S git` in the MSys shell, so that Git becomes available inside MSys.

Comment: Thank you so much, I finally managed it to do it ^^ I needed to download MSYS2 and execute the MinGW.exe in the MSsys Folder then I could run the build.sh and it worked. Only thing I needed to add was that line to CMake: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -static")` otherwise I would get a libpthread.dll errror. Now it works finally and I'm happy to having my first cross-compile Environment working. I just need to take a look on what is going on because I have no knowledge of MinGW nor MSys till today.